# How do I select one row in SQL when another row has same id but a different value in a column?

Tags: sql

I am creating a website where you can share posts with multiple tags, now I encountered the problem that a post is shown multiple times, each one with one tag. In my database I have a table posts and a table tags where you link the post_id. Now my question is: how can I get only one post but multiple tags on this one post?

[screenshot of query in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyRQm.jpg)

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data. As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
Sample data should be *consumable text* in your question. Explain what results you are expecting (as text).

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that most people here want sample data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images or links.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, edit column names if needed:

```
SELECT *, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag) FROM tags WHERE post_id = posts.id) 
FROM posts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT() in MySQL and string_agg() in MS SQL Server

```
SELECT posts.id,GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag)
FROM posts
Left JOIN tags on tags.post_id = posts.id
GROUP BY posts.id
```